# jquery selector to match all elements?

Tags: jquery

I know that if I have this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="list-item test">1</li>
  <li class="list-item">2</li>
  <li class="list-item">3</li>
</ul>
```

Then I can do the following in jQuery:

```
$('ul > li').is('.test');
```

And it will return true because because one of the LIs have the class test. What I would like is a method that only returns true if all of the elements match the selector like this:

```
$('ul > li').all('.test'); // false;
$('ul > li').all('.list-item'); // true
```

Does something like this exist?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if all items have the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485066/check-if-all-items-have-the-same-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it...

```
var allTest = $("ul > li.test").length === $("ul > li").length;
```

or...

```
var allTest = $("ul > li:not(.test)").length === 0;
```

The first does a check to see if the number of li elements with class test is the same as the number of li element (regardless of class).

The second just checks the count of how many don't have the class test.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I've been using, it's a shame that this isn't built in to jQuery (I'd imagine it would be more efficient.) I guess that I have just been spoilt by LINQ.

Comment: Ahh, I prefer the second method. That looks like it would be faster since it doesn't involve searching for everything twice (I'm working with a lot of elements.) Thanks for that, I'll mark this as best answer as soon a SO will let me.

Comment: I think the 2nd one would be the most efficient way of doing it (certainly out of the 2 I suggested).  It may be possible to improve on it, but that's both readable and functional so I'd go with that one.  **Edit:** You ninja'd me - I agree with you :)